# Jquery calculate the total of all textboxes (addition and subtraction)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to calculate the total of multiple fields in a row (*my code will contain multiple rows*) on key press (some of them uses addition method and some of them uses subtract method) but as I am newbie I am not too much familiar to JQuery. In my scenario **B.Salary, Rec.comm, Sal.comm** will add into **total field** and **Advance, deduction** fields will subtract from **total field** and the **adjustment** field will use addition method if contains positive value and subtraction method if contains negative value. I tried my best to figure out some related scenario but no success.

**Here is my HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
    <!-- Adjustment Code Start -->  
    <!-- Heading Data Start -->
    <div class="row parts_title space_bottom" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom:5px;">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1" style="text-align:left !important;">#</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:left !important;">Employee#</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:left !important;">FullName</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">B.Salary</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Advance</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Rec.Comm</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Sal.Comm</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Deduction</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Adjustment</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">Total</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Heading Data End -->  

    <div class="row space_bottom">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input name="checked1" checked="" type="checkbox"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">E17-00001</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">Employee Name 1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="50000" name="txtMonthlyRate1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtAdvance1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="35" name="txtRecovery1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="2350" name="txtsales1" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtdeduction1" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtadjustment1" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="52385" name="txttotal1" type="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row space_bottom">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input name="checked2" checked="" type="checkbox"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">E17-00002</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">Employee Name 2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="10000" name="txtMonthlyRate2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtAdvance2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtRecovery2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0" name="txtsales2" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtdeduction2" type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="0.00" name="txtadjustment2" type="text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><input class="form-control input-sm" value="10000" name="txttotal2" type="text"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Adjustment Code End -->
</div>
</div>
```

**Here is My JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[input[name^=txt]").keyup(function(){
calcPullTotal();
console.log(calcPullTotal);
); 
function calcPullTotal() {
        var basic_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtMonthlyRate]').val());
        var advance_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdvance]').val());
        var recover_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtRecovery]').val());
        var sales_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtSales]').val());
        var deduction_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtDeduction]').val());
        var adjustment_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdjustment]').val());
        var total_sum = ((basic_salary+recover_comm+sales_comm) - (deduction_salary + advance_salary)) + adjustment_salary;
        $('input[name^=txtAdjustment]').val(total_sum);
}

});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: No, I am still looking for some sample, I found some but that doesn't match with my requirements at least a bit, All I found is a sum of all fields only

Comment: This isn't  a free code writing service. It's up to you to do research and show code attempts and people here help you with **your code** that isn't working as expected, not write it all for you or create a tutorials

Comment: I am not asking for a code, I just need a reference to follow to calculate sum of all fields in a row as I already mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A exemple add and remove divs by id  (jquery)

```js
$( '#add' ).click(function() {
    var n = 0;
    n = $( "div" ).length;
    if(n!=1){
      n = n-2;
    }
    n = n+1;
    var div_id = "div_"+n;
    $( document.body ).append( $( '<div id = "'+ div_id+ '">' ));
    $( "#count" ).val("There are " + n + " divs.");
  })
  // Trigger the click to start
  //.trigger( "click" );
 $( '#remove' ).click(function() {
    var n = 0;
    n = $( "div" ).length;
    if(n!=1){
      n = n-2;
    }
    var div_id = "div_"+n;
    $( "#"+div_id ).remove( );
    if(n!=0){
      n = n-1;
    }
    $( "#count" ).val("There are " + n + " divs.");
  })
```

```css
body {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Create and remove divs by id </p>
<input id = "count" type = "text" val = "0">
<button id = "remove" >Remove</button>
<button id = "add" >Add</button>
<br> </br>
```

To add div with id:

```
$( document.body ).append( $( '<div id = "'+ div_id+ '">' ));
```

To remove div with id:

```
$( "#"+div_id ).remove( );
```

To calculate the number of divs:

```
n = $( "div" ).length;
```

For a specific type of class:

```
var numItems = $('.clas').length;
```